# Count unique values in each column of pipe delimited text file using Perl

Tags: python, perl, unix, solaris-10

I have two sample pipe delimited file in my Solaris server home directory as below:

file1.txt:

```
ticker|sedol|cusip|exchnage  
ibm   |ibm_1|ib   |london    
hcl   |     |hcl_02|london    
hp    |hp_01|hpm  |newyork
      |lkp   |lk_2 |newyork
```

file2.txt:

```
exchnage|ticker|sedol|cusip  
london  |goo   |goo_1|gm  
london  |hcl   |     |hcl_02  
newyork |hp    |hp_01|hpm  
newyork |tyl   |     |ty_2
```

I need a result file where we will group the unique count of *ticker, sedol, cusip* by exchange:

expected result file as below:

```
exchnage|ticker|sedol|cusip  
london  |3     |2    |3  
newyork |3     |2    |2
```

I know by using SQL it is easy but unfortunately database can't be involved. Each file size might go up to 300-400 MB. We have do it using Perl preferably or if at all difficult then Python. Primary environment is Solaris, but we can try it in Unix server as well.                                                                                                                                                        Now added need is that "exchange" Column position can by anywhere in both the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the most elegant, but the fastest I crafted for your new requirements:

```
import glob
import os
import sys

path = "/tmp"
file_mask = "file*.txt"
results = {}

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, file_mask)):
    column_names = {}
    exchange_col = None
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line_num, line in enumerate(f.xreadlines()):
            # process header
            if not line_num:
                line_parsed = line.strip().split("|")
                for column_num, column in enumerate(line_parsed):
                    if column.strip() == "exchnage":
                        exchange_col = column_num
                    else:
                        column_names[column_num] = column.strip()
                if exchange_col is None:
                    print "Can't find exchnage field"
                    sys.exit(1)
                continue
            line_parsed = line.strip().split("|")
            if len(line_parsed) != len(column_names) + 1:
                continue
            # prepare empty structure for excahnge, if not added yet
            if not line_parsed[exchange_col].strip() in results:
                results[line_parsed[exchange_col].strip()] = {column_name:set() for column_name in column_names.values()}
            # add uniq items to exchange
            for column_num, column in enumerate(line_parsed):
                column_val = column.strip()
                # add only non empty values
                if column_val and column_num != exchange_col:  
                    results[line_parsed[exchange_col].strip()][column_names[column_num]].add(column_val)

column_names = column_names.values()
print "exchnage|" + "|".join("%8s" %c for c in column_names)
for exchange, values in results.iteritems():
    print "%8s|" % exchange + "|".join("%8s" % str(len(values[column])) for column in column_names)
```

program output (as input your new files with different columns order were used):

```
$ python parser.py
exchnage|  ticker|   sedol|   cusip
 newyork|       2|       2|       3
  london|       3|       2|       3
```

Comment: @purnendumaity, be aware that it matches files structure from your example, and operate column numbers, not names. so if you have different number of columns in files, or columns order, it may not work.

Comment: @Dieselist..u r right. now that "exchange" column is in column 30 so it should I modified as below:                                                                                                         # prepare empty structure for excahnge, if not added yet
            if not line_parsed[0] in results:
                results[line_parsed[0]] = [set() for i in xrange(len(line_parsed[30:]))]
            # add uniq items to exchange
            for column_num, column in enumerate(line_parsed[30:]):

Comment: @purnendumaity, could you provide new format? will it be persistance (can the column numbers be hardcoded)? shall we operate by column no or by name?

Comment: u are very helpful...we will operate by column no, what about if we use pandas and then straight SQL root...possible but then additional package installation etc things involved...i don't think they will agree

Comment: @purnendumaity, I've updated my answer with new code, that arranged to satisfy your new requirements. For now it automatically figures out column order in files.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %unique_ticker_count;
my %unique_sedol_count;
my %unique_cusip_count;

my @headers = split( '|', <DATA> );
print @headers;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my ( $exchange, $ticker, $sedol, $cusip ) = split( /\|/, $line );
    if ( $ticker =~ m/\w/ ) { $unique_ticker_count{$exchange}{$ticker}++; }
    if ( $sedol =~ m/\w/ )  { $unique_sedol_count{$exchange}{$sedol}++; }
    if ( $cusip =~ m/\w/ )  { $unique_cusip_count{$exchange}{$cusip}++; }
}

print Dumper \%unique_ticker_count;

foreach my $exchange ( keys %unique_ticker_count ) {
    print join( "|",
        $exchange,
        scalar keys %{ $unique_ticker_count{$exchange} } || 0,
        scalar keys %{ $unique_sedol_count{$exchange} }  || 0,
        scalar keys %{ $unique_cusip_count{$exchange} }  || 0,
        ),
        "\n";
}

__DATA__
exchnage|ticker|sedol|cusip  
london  |ibm   |ibm_1|ib  
london  |hcl   |     |hcl_02  
newyork |hp    |hp_01|hpm  
newyork |lkp   |lk_2 |
london  |goo   |goo_1|gm  
london  |hcl   |     |hcl_02  
newyork |hp    |hp_01|hpm  
newyork |tyl   |     |ty_2
```

Will print:

```
newyork |3|2|2
london  |3|2|3
```

I will leave it to you to handle the file opening and processing - this is merely illustrative of the approach you could take.

Comment: this  _DATA_ are you taking assumption as a single file ? I have two file.. then are you suggesting to merge them ? one file might have more column than another file then will merge work? ...I only have the prior knowledge of which column to check/count

Comment: `DATA` is a way of inlining data in perl, which makes illustration and posting code easier. You can quite easily `open ( my $input, "<", $filename ) or die $!`; and then `while ( <$input> ) { ` instead. this will work for multiple files being processed, because the collation happens at the end. (Just remember to discard the header line from each file)

Comment: @Sobrique..as per new scenario I have to work by column position rather than name

Answer (score 0):

I think, first you'll need to create a list of dictionaries from the files, like:
**{'exchnage':'london','ticker':'ibm','sedol':'ibm_1','cusip':'ib'}**. Than you need a for-each satement to add all the values to a list, but only, when the value aren't None, empty & value isn't already in the list. Then you have got all unique values in the list, you juts need to count them.
**You'll need to do this with all the column in the file.**
After that, you'll need to write this in a file.

Comment: I am more into R programming and little in shell...Perl is a whole new world for me. Could you please post a little code and which Perl package we need to use ? if you feel it is big..you can send me at purnendumaity@rediffmail.com. I really need this.

Comment: @purnendumaity You wrote "python" when you asked the question. I can see, you removed it. I don't know, how can you solve in perl. It's the logic of the problem, which can implemented for the most of languages.

Comment: I haven't removed Python...as per the mandate from above Perl is first priority but Python solution will also do....I can see Python tag is still there in my question. actually in that specific system already many things are in Perl..hope u understand